# Completeness of Operator space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Assume $(X,\|\cdot\|_X),(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ are normed spaces and $\dim X\geq 1$. The following holds:

$Y$ complete $\iff$ $\mathscr L(X,Y)$ complete.

The latter denotes the space of bounded operators between $X,Y$. The right implication is not hard to prove, but I was unable to find a proof of the left implication. Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think [Nicolas Bourbaki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) can figure this out by themselves...

Comment: You need some assumptions on $X$ to get the reverse implication. If $X=\{0\}$, for instance, this is false. I think a natural equivalence would be: $Y$ is complete if and only if $L(X,Y)$ is complete for every normed space $X$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I require that dim $X >0$, the proof below would work, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_0\in X$ be a fixed unit vector, and choose a direct complement of it:
$$X=\langle x_0\rangle\oplus X_1$$
using e.g. [Hahn-Banach theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem).

Then, let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, and consider $\phi_n:X\to Y$ mapping $x_0\mapsto y_n$ and $\phi_n|_{X_1}=0$. Then $(\phi_n)$ is also Cauchy, so $\phi_n\to\phi$ in operator norm for some bounded $\phi:X\to Y$. Pointwise convergence follows, so we have $\phi|_{X_1}=0$, and let $y:=\phi(x_0)$, this is going to be the limit of $(y_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why would I require the Hahn-Banach theorem though?

Comment: How do you compute the norm of $\phi_n$? In other words, what is the norm of a vector $x=tx_0+x_1$? All you can say is $\|\phi_n\|\geq \frac{\|y_n\|}{\|x_0\|}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{y_n\}\subset Y$ be a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent. Fix $f\colon X\to \Bbb R$ a non-zero continuous linear functional and define $T_n(x):=f(x)y_n$. Then $T_n$ is a sequence of linear bounded operators and $\lVert T_n-T_m\rVert=\lVert f\rVert_{X'}\lVert y_n-y_m\rVert$, so the sequence $\{T_n\}$ is Cauchy for the operator norm. If it converged to some $T$, we would have a contradiction taking $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$.

We need to ensure the existence of $f$. It's possible to do that thanks to Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: It's the same as mine, with the correspondence $X_1=\ker f$.

Comment: @Berci Yes. With the tiny yet important difference that $\|T_n-T_m\|=\|f\| \|y_n-y_m\|$ is made explicit while your argument leaves it to the reader to figure out $\|\phi_n-\phi_m\|=C\|y_n-y_m\|$ for some $C>0$. I guess some readers, like me I confess, tend to be lazy sometimes. But I'll upvote both answers.