# Showing that a set of operators is not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I want to show that,

for $X$ a normed space, $T \in L(X;X)$,

the set $\{S \in L(X;X) : ST = TS\}$ is not closed in $L(X;X)$.

We might be able to construct a sequence $(S_n)$ whose the limit is not in $L(X;X
)$. However, I am struggling to find a concrete example.

Comment: Well, it depends on $T$. E.g. with $T=I$ the set is the whole $L(X, X) $ which is closed.

Comment: $X$ complete $\implies L(X,X)$ complete: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346434/completeness-of-operator-space.

Comment: You write "Since $L(X;X)$ is not complete and thus not closed, ..."  Being complete is a property of a **metric space**, whereas being closed is a property of a subset of that space ($L(X; X)$ is closed as a subset of itself, whatever topology you take).

Comment: I am familiar with the fact that if $X$ is complete, then $L(X;X)$ is complete as well. However, in this case $X$ is just a normed space and not necessarily Banach. So we don't actually know whether $L(X;X) is closed, do we?

Comment: The fact that $L(X;X)$ is a closed subset of the metric space $L(X;X)$ is an axiom, and has nothing to do with $L(X;X)$ being complete or not.

Comment: Ok, indeed, the  "Since $L(X;X)$ is not complete and thus not closed" part was wrong.

Comment: Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla showed (and I agree with the answer) that the set is closed, so you cannot show that it is not.  Perhaps you meant something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in what topology? A reasonable possibility is using the operator norm on $L(X,X)$. In the operator norm, the operator product
$$L(X,X)\times L(X,X)\longrightarrow L(X,X)$$
$$(R,S)\longmapsto RS$$
is continuous and your set is obviously closed.